# Are there any differences between conforming versus downcasting in regards to delegate properties?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I was working through a coding exercise and I was curious as to how everything works together when using delegates.  Without getting any compiling errors from Xcode, I was able to remove the class's conformity to NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate and set the delegate property using downcasting or the keyword 'as'.  If this works then what are the pros and cons of composing the class this way?

```
import Cocoa

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var speakButton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: NSButton!
    let speechSynth = NSSpeechSynthesizer()
    var isSpeaking: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateButtons()
        }
    }

    override var windowNibName: NSNib.Name? {
        return NSNib.Name("MainWindowController")

    }

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        updateButtons()

        speechSynth.delegate = self as? NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate

    }

    // MARK: - Action methods
    @IBAction func speakIt(sender: NSButton) {

        //Get tuype-in text as a strin
        let string = textField.stringValue
        if string.isEmpty {
            print("string from \(textField) is empty")
        } else {
            speechSynth.startSpeaking(string)
            isSpeaking = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stopIt(sender: NSButton) {
        speechSynth.stopSpeaking()
        isSpeaking = false
    }

    func updateButtons(){
        if isSpeaking {
            speakButton.isEnabled = false
            stopButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            speakButton.isEnabled = true
            stopButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    // MARK: - NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate

    func speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, didFinishSpeaking finishedSpeaking: Bool) {
        isSpeaking = false
        print("finishedSpeaking = \(finishedSpeaking)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it actually work when you used `as? NSSpeechSynthesizer` or did it just compile?  My experience is that `as? ProtocolName` will return `nil` if you don't conform to `ProtocolName`.

Comment: @vacawama No it didn't work so your experience is still right.  The warning I received was 'Treating a forced downcast to 'NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate' as optional will never produce 'nil'' which is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It you remove the protocol conformance and just conditionally cast `speechSynth.delegate = self as? NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate`, it will compile but that will set the `delegate` to `nil` at runtime, even *if* you implement all of the required methods.

You must adopt `NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` for this to work.  Of course, it is also in your best interest to do so because the Swift compiler will then warn you if you have left out any required methods.